# ExecuteScalar with formview

Tags: executescalar

i have form view i wrote this code in event sqlds_inserted

```
text1.text=e.Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

to have the id for the last inserted record
it works but every time i add record it inserts tow records with the same data
when i delete this code
it works fine

Comment: my sql statment 
INSERT INTO MainData(Emp_Identity_Number, Emp_IdentityID) VALUES (@Emp_Identity_Number, @Emp_IdentityID); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: are you sure that you statement is executed only once?

Answer (score 2):

The formview is inserting a record via the default sqldatasource (or objectdatasource, etc...) and then you are calling another insert via the ExecuteScalar method (e in your code represents the datasource you are using).